# Converting "Some quote enclosed text" to Some_underlined_text with resharper

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-macros

I have up to now been using a macro to convert "This sort of text" to This_sort_of_text.

This is very useful for typing test class names.

(Details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/elee/archive/2010/02/28/my-bdd-naming-macro.aspx)

Unfortunately Visual Studio 11 (2012) does not support macros any more.

Can the same be done with resharper?

If not i might look into creating a VS Extension... unless anyone knows one exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a ReSharper plugin for it, it could be easier than a VS extension. See here for more info [Resharper API for selected text and remote code generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405690/resharper-api-for-selected-text-and-remote-code-generation) . You can use document.ReplaceText method to make modifications.